# Digital signature with iText7

Tags: c#, cryptography, bouncycastle, private-key, itext7

I've encountered a problem when trying to implement digital signature with iText7. According to the documentation of iText and couple examples I need to implement `IExternalSignature` [(here)](http://itextsupport.com/apidocs/iText7/latest/com/itextpdf/signatures/IExternalSignature.html), like so: `IExternalSignature signature = new PrivateKeySignature(pk, digestAlgorithm);` but this is where I get the exception:

`var pk = Org.BouncyCastle.Security.DotNetUtilities.GetKeyPair(cert.PrivateKey).Private;`

[image]

which basically means "Invalid key to use in the current state"(?).

Most of the examples are from older version of iText library and Java (I'm using C#) and I cant quite figute it out.

I'll be very grateful for any tips. Thanks!

EDIT:
Here's some example code just to replicate the exception:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string output = "D:/Development/TestApp/testOutputMoje.pdf";
        string input = "D:/Development/TestApp/testInput.pdf";

        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(input);
        string digestAlgorithm = DigestAlgorithms.SHA256;

        List<X509Certificate2> oCertChain = new List<X509Certificate2>();

        //getting certificates from store
        X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.My);
        store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
        foreach (var oCert in store.Certificates)
        {
            oCertChain.Add(oCert);
        }
        store.Close();

        //siginig with first certificate - just example
        var cert = oCertChain[0];   

        //exception here:
        var pk = Org.BouncyCastle.Security.DotNetUtilities.GetKeyPair(cert.PrivateKey).Private; 

        X509Certificate[] bouncyCert = { Org.BouncyCastle.Security.DotNetUtilities.FromX509Certificate(cert) };

        StampingProperties stampProp = new StampingProperties();
        stampProp.PreserveEncryption();

        IExternalSignature signature = new PrivateKeySignature(pk, digestAlgorithm);

        PdfSigner signer = new PdfSigner(reader, new FileStream(output, FileMode.Create), stampProp);
        signer.SignDetached(signature, bouncyCert, null, null, null, 0, CryptoStandard.CADES);

        reader.Close();
    }
```

Couple more informations about the certificate (I cant show You any details unfortunately)

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Indeed, you don't show the value of `digestAlgorithm`, you don't tell us the basic aspects of your key pair (don't post the key pair itself unless it's merely a test key pair, but tell us about algorithms and parameters, key sizes, key usages,...). Furthermore, a stack trace of the exception would be helpful.

Comment: I've edited post to add some more info, I hope that's enough to find solution?

Comment: Is it possible that your private key value cannot be retrieved? E.g. because it's located on some device, a smart card or usb dongle? In that case `DotNetUtilities.GetKeyPair` indeed won't work, it attempts to retrieve the actual private key value. I assume you should switch from `PrivateKeySignature` to `AsymmetricAlgorithmSignature` which directly works with the `RSACryptoServiceProvider` or `DSACryptoServiceProvider`.

Answer (score 0):

problem is in certificate. It has to be marked as "Exportable". I don't know how solve this case, but in my case I used own certificate this way:

```
var cert = new X509Certificate2();
cert.Import(File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\temp\certificate.cer"), "password", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);
```

This works.

You need to find the way to change your certificate flag. Maybe something with `store.Open(OpenFlags.MaxAllowed)`, but this doesn't work.